# Difference Between HTML <audio>, <bgsound> and <embed> audio tags

Tags: html, tags, html5-audio

What is the difference between `<audio>`, `<bgsound>` and `<embed>` tags ?

I am trying to add background sound on my website. tried `<embed>` but it doesn't works on mobile . similarly `<bgsound>` had some limitations. `<audio>` tag works for me.

can anybody explain how each differ from one another?

Comment: Note that `<audio>` doesn't play the sound if you hide the controls and play it automatically on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> < bgsound > : The HTML  tag is used to play a soundtrack in the background. This tag is for Internet Explorer only.

**`< bgsound >`**  :  Only For Internet Explorer

**Summary :**  The HTML Background Sound Element () is an Internet Explorer element associating a background sound with a page.

**Example:**

```
<bgsound src="sound1.mid">
<bgsound src="sound2.au" loop="infinite">
```

> < audio > & < video >  :  Standard Way To Implement audio and video in Website currently

`< audio >`   :   HTML5  element specifies a standard way to embed audio in a web page. ( ogg,mp3.etc. supported )

**Example :**

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio
```

> < embed >  : 3rd partiy Plugins like Java application , Flash apps.. etc,

`< embed >`  : its 3rd Partiy Plugins which are outdated now. ( The  element creates an embedded panel in which a third-party application, such as a Flash-based object, can run.

**Example :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Embed Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<embed src="www.abc./html/yourfile.mdi" width="250" height="100" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<audio>` is the standard, HTML 5, method to include sound. Use this.

`<bgsound>` is a non-standard, Internet Explorer only, method to include sound that predates HTML 5.

`<embed>` is a means to include content that has no native support and is expected to be handled by a plugin.